# Rails: models and database tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Rails newbie here. If I have a model and a table associated with it, can I refer to the table's attributes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. ActiveRecord maps tables to your models.

You can inspect the official ActiveRecord tutorial:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ModelName.attribute_name should do it.